# Error when trying to use LoginRequiredMiddleware in Django

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for tutorial project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'tw)pqpbi)r_z1lr0j#h1m6m)wy*8b+4-iorw#%-t3#x)6wuv8$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_ = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'tutorial.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tutorial.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tutorial.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/'



EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
    r'^accounts/logout/$',
    r'^accounts/register/$',

)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from tutorial import views
#from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^$',views.login_redirect,name="login_redirect"),
]
```

middleware.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import re

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS +=[re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def __call__(self,request):
        response = self.get_response
        return redirect
    def process_view (self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

        if not user.is_authenticated():
            if not any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS):
                return redirec(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

and views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from tutorial import views
from accounts.form import Registrationform,EditProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm,PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def home(request):
    numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
    name="jay"
    args={'myName':name}

    return render(request,'accounts/home.html',args)
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Registrationform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('please fill all the fields and make sure new password must be match')
    else:
        form = Registrationform()
        args={'form' : form}
        return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)
@login_required
def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user' : request.user}
    return render(request,'accounts/profile.html',args)
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #<p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
        if request.method=="POST":
            form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/accounts/profile')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("please go back and write correct vaues")
        else:
            form  =  EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            args = {'form' : form}
            return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',args)
    else:
        HttpResponse("hllo")
        return redirect('/accounts/login')
@login_required
def change_password(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST,user=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
                return redirect('/accounts/profile')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("password does not match,go back and try again")
        else:
            form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
            args = {'form' : form}
            return render(request,'accounts/change_password.html',args)
    else:
        return redirect ('/accounts/login')
```

When I go to the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/` it gives an error like:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

I found that when I delete `'tutorial.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware'` from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` it works fine but after adding it doesn't work. I also tried to change `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to `MIDDLEWARE` but then it's giving me an error like

```
WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user.
```

i have removed MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and then it not work
and the the terminal shows:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 14, 2018 - 05:49:00
Django version 1.9, using settings 'tutorial.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /accounts/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    if test_func(request.user):
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Do you get any output in the logs/terminal from the django app when you hit that URL?

Comment: yes. i added what terminal shows in question

Comment: In your settings, you have `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/'`. The request showing the error is `/accounts/`. However, I can't see url handlers for either of those 2 URLs. Are they both correct? What view is expected to handle these and where is the url hander for them? I'm assuming you're using [django-user-accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/master/account/urls.py)?

Comment: You sure the request object has attribute user at the time middleware is executed? From what i understand, django adds that attribute to the `WSGIRequest object`.

Comment: Note you shouldn't share secrets from your settings like `SECRET_KEY`. Remember to change this before you deploy your project.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a mismatch between your `settings.py` (generated using Django 2.0.2.) and your logs (Django version 1.9).

Your `LoginRequiredMiddleware` looks like new-style middleware (requires Django 1.10+), so you should be using the `MIDDLEWARE` setting instead of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. Run your server using the latest 2.0.x release instead.

If you can’t upgrade to Python 3 and Django 2.0, then you should use `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` instead of `MIDDLEWARE` with Django < 1.10. However your `LoginRequiredMiddleware` is designed for new style `MIDDLEWARE` and will not work with `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Finally, note that Django 1.10 and older are unsupported and do not receive security fixes, so you should try to use at least Django 1.11 LTS.

Comment: yes sir.i have update my code(i have used MIDDLWARE) and then output of terminal is as shows in question(i have updated question)